# Whether vs. Regardless in this sentence

Tags: word-usage

I wrote:

> Whether these powers are good or not, or whether they have good intentions or not, people dislike to see their presence in the region.

I suspect if I had to use "Regardless" or "No matter" instead of "whether" and "whether" is not applicable here.

Comment: As a learner: I think that is totally fine, but, stylistically, one might come up with a better phrasing.

Comment: Both *regardless* and *no matter* could easily be substituted—but only if the sentence is rephrased to accommodate them. If all you do is change the word itself and nothing else, the result would be ungrammatical.